# HP Probook 4520s mobile broadband

Tags: wireless, drivers, 13.10, atheros

I have installed ubuntu 13.10 but it doesn't see the mobile broadband on my HP Probook 4520s. I don't know linux very well and have no idea what to do. The internal modem is Qualcomm Atheros AR9285.  I suspect that I'm missing a driver. What can I do? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu. You might want to change the title of your post a bit, as it doesn't say much about your problem.

Comment: Are you referring to a wireless issue or a mobile broadband issue to be exact?? the modem model you specifies shows as a wireless adapter

Comment: Mobile broadband. It worked with Win XP through HP Connection Manager. I want my sim card to connect to the Internet.

Comment: I go into the network wizard, select mobile broadband. Then country (South Africa) and provider (Cell C). Then save. But the connection isn't listed when I click on the network icon.